# Adding String ArrayList into properties File java?

Tags: java, file, properties

Is it possible to store a String ArrayList into a properties file and then read and modify the list in a simple way?

I think i will need to run example:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
File f = new File("MyText.txt");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f,"");
p.load(in);

ArrayList<String> list = p.getProperty("list");
```

<-- Modify the list and then open a OutputStream and save the p object again ?
Is this possible to manage easily in Java?

Comment: And how do you expect to store the `ArrayList` in the property file? I mean what is going to be written in the text file against the entry `list`?

Comment: I want to store only file Paths as Strings, so what i really want is something like a ArrayList<String> with say 5 File Paths that can change sometimes dynamically.

Comment: You simply cannot store an object as text.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a delimiter, say '|', to join the Strings in your ArrayList. When saving your list, use this code (`String.join()` needs Java 8):

```
String listAsString = String.join("|", list);
properties.put("list", listAsString);
```

When retrieving the list, do this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(properties.get("list").toString().split("\\|"));
```

Comment: Thanks alot will test this!